# Integration of nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to solve it as shown in image file.
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{-y^4}{6}+2cy+d}}=dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general$$I=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{ay^4+2cy+d}}$$ write
$$ay^4+2c y+d=a(y-p)(y-q)(y-r)(y-s)$$ where $(p,q,r,s)$ are the roots of the polynomial and you will end with a nasty elliptic integral of the first kind.

Before any simplification, a CAS produces

$$I=-\frac{2 (y-p) (y-q) \sqrt{\frac{(p-q) (y-r)}{(p-y) (q-r)}} \sqrt{\frac{(p-q)
   (y-s)}{(p-y) (q-s)}} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(p-s) (y-q)}{(q-s)
   (y-p)}}\right)|\frac{(p-r) (q-s)}{(q-r) (p-s)}\right)}{(p-q) \sqrt{\frac{(p-s)
   (q-y)}{(p-y) (q-s)}} \sqrt{a (y-p) (y-q) (y-r) (y-s)}}$$